# C++ view Mutex value in watch window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, debugging

is it possible to view the value of a Mutex or Semaphore in Watch winodw in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a debugger could see the internal state of a synchronization object then a program could as well.  Allowing it to circumvent the API and use the object in a thread-unsafe manner.  This is for your own good, but of course an enormous pita when trying to debug threading problems.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the state of kernel objects like mutexes and semaphores using a [kernel debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) (Kd or WinDbg) and the `!handle` and `!object` extension commands. Note that kernel debugging requires a second PC (though a VM guest may suffice in some circumstances).

Also note that critical sections are not kernel objects (though they may contain a handle to one), so you should be able to view some information about them with a user-mode debugger.

Comment: WinDbg can inspect kernel objects when attached to a USER mode application. There is absolutely no requirement to do kernel debugging, when all you want to do is inspect a kernel object (e.g. Lock count, Recursion count, Contention count, etc. of a synchronization object).

Answer (score 1):

No. because the value you holding are just handle to internal window structures.